# Docker fails with "Admin permissions are required to run a server on a port below 1024" when runs at 80

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, containers, port

In my React JS app, my docker container is running at port 80 and I am trying to run my host also at port 80.

But, when I try to run the docker image, I am getting permission error because of which my pod is not executing.

It is failing with this **issue**:

```
 Port:           80/TCP
 Host Port:      0/TCP
 State:          Waiting
   Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
 Last State:     Terminated
   Reason:       Completed
   Exit Code:    0
```

I did the port mapping in `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "export PORT=80 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I am also exposing the port in Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent
RUN npm i @azure/msal-react
RUN mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app
USER node
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I have configured the envoirnment variable in `.env` file

```
PORT=80
```

And, my yml files looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: <app name>
  namespace: development
  labels:
    env: development
    app: <app name>
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    env: development
    app: <app name>
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <app name>
  namespace: development
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      env: development
      app: <app name>
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        env: development
        app: <app name>
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: <app name>
        image: <image>:<version>
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 500Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
          periodSeconds: 3
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: azurecontainerregistry
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: <app name>
  namespace: development
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: <certificate>
  rules:
  - host: <host address>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: <app name>
            port:
                number: 80
```

I have gone through many links though nothing is helping. Looking for some suggestion.
When I am trying to run host port with 3000 docker container still fails.

Thanks
Please

Comment: The nodeservice within your container tries to run at port 80. In unix-based systems that is not allowed for non-admin users (like the user `node` is) So either (all action *within the container*) use port > 1024, run your service as root, or use something like https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443

Comment: ok. thankyou for explanation. In that case, I prefer to run use port > 1024 and how exactly can I run it as root? I am trying for port 3000

Comment: For that , I changed .env file port=3000 and In Dockerfile, updated the expose=3000 but still getting this issue > Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.240.0.181:80/": dial tcp 10.240.0.181:80: connect: connection refused <